# Multi-Threading in Multiplayer Strategy Games

Tags: .net, multithreading, building

In most online multiplayer strategy games, players build buildings and attack to get better at the game.

But, there's one thing I've never understood.
A player could start building some building, that'll last for 3 hours.

But then, even though he disconnects, the building keeps getting built.

That, of course, means that it's server sided.

But to keep the server responsive while the building is being built, it has to be on a separate thread, which then becomes a problem.

Think about 500 players connected to one server, each building 2 buildings.
That'll account to 1000 threads, and as a result the server would be unresponsive.

So how is it done correctly? I want to program a similar game (for Desktop with C#) but I have no idea how to manage the server sided constructions with efficient multi-threading.

Comment: *maybe* this is better on Programmers.SE  However this is a conversation question and not really a good fit for the SE / SO format. [Please consider reading this.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: What would the thread actually be doing if it needs to lock up/load the server? Why not just set a timer (or just make a quick note in the database) to quickly set up the built house in 2 hours and let the thread be on its merry way to do other things?

Comment: He thinks that there are little people in the CPU which are actually building the building.  They call themselves threads.  MAYBE with a little bit of logic, you could derive that a "building" takes 2 hours to build and that if it's one been one hour, then your building is 50% of the way done - all with out a thread running for 1 hour...

Comment: Dan, this is half a solution. A thread running for one hour just for one player's building is still not a good thing.

Comment: Joachim, I actually thought about a timer for 2 hours, but the only problem is I want to update the time passed every second, and not just after 2 hours. A timer that'll sleep for 2 hours can't update the situation every second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very complicated topic actually :)

The simple answer is that you have only 1 main game thread that actually runs the game. Each player opens a connection to the server. The server can handle each connection in a thread or more commonly will use non-blocking sockets with a single network thread.

In C# I have used the async socket methods which use IOCP behind the scenes - this means you roughly have 1 thread managing the actual sockets and then a thread pool actually delegating to handle the data once its in memory.

If this isn't making much sense to you I recommend doing some reading on game design and networking. I would recommend using something like lidgren if you don't want to write your own networking code.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for your answer. I chose UDP sockets for my game, so there are no real connections (the virtual UDP connections are being done with a timer for each client, not a new thread, and a client that sends a Heartbeat packet each second). But how can I make the server construct all the buildings on one thread? Just in a chronological order? Because with every second, it has to both update the time, and both send it to all clients connected. I have some experience in networking, but one thread managing all this doesn't actually make sense, and I'm willing to write my own code.

Comment: I would recommend using lidgren for handling the UDP connections. It will give you callbacks on incoming messages.

You will want want to then have a thread-safe data structure to pass data between the threads. The main game loop would check the incoming messages data structure and handle it during its main loop.

You will probably also want an "outgoing messages" threadsafe structure for passing data back to the network thread to send to clients.

Comment: I don't see it necessary, since I have just one thread with a Receive method, and when a message is received, it opens a new thread to handle the request (if needed). Handling the connections isn't a problem at all, there's just a timer for each client (System.Timers.Timer). Also, are timers new threads (is making a new timer same as making a new thread, or it works differently)?

Comment: I think that in order to explain to you everything you need to know would go way beyond the scope of this single question. I would recommend learning server side game programming using a site like http://www.gamedev.net/

Comment: OK, I will use it. Also, as I said I have some experience. A project I made was a small Remote Administration Tool, that uses UDP sockets to let someone control PC's of people that installed his file (with functions like Shutdown, Keylogger and such things). This is basic packet sending, but as you say, I probably have a lot to learn. Thanks a lot!